# Find months between two dates

Tags: r, date

I have this tibble

```
library(tibble)

tibble(site = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), date = c("01/12/21", "07/06/22", "02/12/22", "30/07/23"), `last date` = c("01/03/22", "07/07/22", "02/12/23", "30/07/24"))
```

I need to add a column that lists all months included between `date` and `last date`.

How can I get below output using R code? The column `months` should contain only unique months (so a maximum of 12 elements in each string).

I have tried various ways of using seq.Date without success.

```
tibble(site = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), date = c("01/12/21", "07/06/22", "02/12/22", "30/07/23"), `last date` = c("01/03/22", "07/07/22", "02/12/23", "30/07/24"), months = c("December, January, February, March", "June, July", "December, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November", "July, August, September, October, November, December, January, February, March, April, May, June"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(months = pmap_chr(
    across(2:3, ~ as.Date(.x, "%d/%m/%y")),
    ~ toString(unique(strftime(seq(.x, .y, by = "month"), "%b")))
  ))

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   site  date     `last date` months                                                    
#   <chr> <chr>    <chr>       <chr>                                                     
# 1 a     01/12/21 01/03/22    Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar                                        
# 2 b     07/06/22 07/07/22    Jun, Jul                                                  
# 3 c     02/12/22 02/12/23    Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov
# 4 d     30/07/23 30/07/24    Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan, Mar, Apr, May, Jun
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `as.Date`, `seq.Date` and `unique` in `Map`.

```
> transform(dat, months=Map(seq.Date, as.Date(date, '%d/%m/%y'), 
+                           as.Date(last.date, '%d/%m/%y'), by='month') |>
+             lapply(format, '%b') |> lapply(unique) |> sapply(toString))
  site     date last.date                                                     months
1    a 01/12/21  01/03/22                                         Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar
2    b 07/06/22  07/07/22                                                   Jun, Jul
3    c 02/12/22  02/12/23 Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov
4    d 30/07/23  30/07/24      Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan, Mar, Apr, May, Jun
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(site = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), date = c("01/12/21", 
"07/06/22", "02/12/22", "30/07/23"), last.date = c("01/03/22", 
"07/07/22", "02/12/23", "30/07/24")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with standardized month abbreviations ("Jan" instead of "January"), you could do this by indexing `month.abb` after wrapping `seq.Date` with `lubridate::month`. Finally, `paste` it all together and`sapply` will iterate through the rows (since `seq.Date` doesnt accept vector inputs):

```
data$months <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(data)), \(x)
       paste(month.abb[lubridate::month(seq.Date(data$date[x], data$`last date`[x], by = "month"))], 
             collapse = ", "))

#   site  date       `last date` months                                                         
#   <chr> <date>     <date>      <chr>                                                          
# 1 a     2021-12-01 2022-03-01  Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar                                             
# 2 b     2022-06-07 2022-07-07  Jun, Jul                                                       
# 3 c     2022-12-02 2023-12-02  Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
# 4 d     2023-07-30 2024-07-30  Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan, Mar, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul
```

Data

```
data <- tibble::tibble(site = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), date = c("01/12/21", "07/06/22", "02/12/22", "30/07/23"), `last date` = c("01/03/22", "07/07/22", "02/12/23", "30/07/24"))
data[-1] <- lapply(data[-1], lubridate::dmy)
```